# How to update cell props programmatically in Mui-Datagrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

We are using Mui-Datagrid component where the users can upload and edit their data.
Within `customID` column definition, there are the `preProcessEditCellProps` and `renderEditCell` properties.

`const columns = [ { field: "customID", headerName: "customID", width: 100, editable: true, preProcessEditCellProps: customIDValidation, renderEditCell: renderEditCell } ... ];`

The `preProcessEditCellProps` checking the validity of the input **only** when the user is typing.
If the length of the value is less than 3 then it returns `error` & `errorMessage` and then pass it to `renderEditCell` as a props.

The thing is that we have a submit button where we want to validate the whole cells before submitting the data and then update the cell props in order to show which cells are invalid and style them as well.

I tried to figure out how to update these cell props using the apiRef of Mui DataGrid and i couldn't find any suitable method to achieve that.

attached codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-snow-pmj64y?file=/src/App.js

Any ideas are more than welcome
Thanks!

Comment: i have the same issue, any idea on how to solve it ?